# How to put ggplot2 ticks labels between dollars?

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, latex, tikz

In order to "convert" a `ggplot2` graphic to a pdf LaTeX graphic with the `tikzDevice` package, I'd like to put the axis ticks labels between two `$`. Of course I can do it if I specify manually the tick labels, but how to do when using the automatic tick labels ? (in particular when using dates on the x-axis it is hard to specify manually the labels).

## Update - solution with axis labels formatter

Based on @agstudy's answer, I have written the `dollarify()` formatter for numerical labels:

```
dollarify <- function(){
    function(x) paste0("$",x,"$")
}
```

and the `datify()` formatter for dates:

```
datify <- function(){
  function(x){
    split <- stringr::str_split_fixed(as.character(x),"-",3)
    out <- character(nrow(split))
    for(i in 1:length(out)){
      out[i] <- paste0("\\formatdate{", split[i,3], "}{", split[i,2], "}{", split[i,1], "}")
    }
    out
  }
}
```

which generates a LaTeX code to be used with the `datetime` package:

```
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
```

Below is a screenshot of a rendering, using the following scale for the x-axis :

```
scale_x_date(breaks="2 months", labels=datify())
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear what you want to do but I think you are looking for an axis labels formatter.

```
## forma  :you can give here any date format 
dollar_date_format <- function (forma = "%H:%M"){
    function(x) paste0("$",format(x,forma),"$")
}
```

Then using some data ( please provide reproducible example next time) you can use it like this:

```
DF <- data.frame(time=Sys.time()+1:10,count=1:10)
library(ggplot2)
qplot(x=time,y=count,data=DF)+
    scale_x_datetime(labels = dollar_date_format(forma = "%M:%S"))+
    xlab("Time (dollars)") +
    theme(axis.text.x =element_text(size=20))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generically be able to modify the axis labels, you can run the plot, use `ggplot_build()` to get the plotted labels back, then add e.g. `scale_x_continuous()`/`scale_x_date()` with custom labels on the rendered breaks. You will need to tweak it depending on datatypes (look in the `build` variable to see what data's available).

You might want to use `$x/y.labels` or `$x/y.major_source` depending on datatype

```
x=c("2013-03-22","2013-04-24","2013-07-01","2013-09-13")
y=c(1,2,3,4)
#any ggplot object
g<-qplot(as.Date(x),y)

#call the rendered axis labels
build<-ggplot_build(g)
xrng<-data.frame(build$panel$ranges[[1]]$x.major_source,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
yrng<-data.frame(build$panel$ranges[[1]]$y.labels,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
colnames(xrng)<-"value"
colnames(yrng)<-"value"

#create custom labels
xrng$lab<-paste0("$",row.names(xrng),"$")
yrng$lab<-paste0("$",yrng$value,"$")

#re-render with custom labels
g+scale_x_date(breaks=as.Date(xrng$value),labels=xrng$lab) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=as.numeric(yrng$value),labels=yrng$lab)
```

[image]

Comment: Good to know that, thank you. However I accept @agstudy's answer cause it is cleaner for the present problem.